# Condition has length greater than 1 in while loop

Tags: r, zoo

I´m writing a function so it returns the last business day of the month given the month and year.

It uses is.bizday from bizdays package. is.bizday returns TRUE if the given date is business day or FALSE otherwise.

My function:

```
library(bizdays)

UltDiaLabor <- function(mesanio) {

  ult<-as.Date(as.yearmon(mesanio, "%m%Y"), frac = 1)

  while(!is.bizday(ult)) {
    ult=ult-1 
    }
  return(ult)

}
```

It starts from the last day of the month provided with as.yearmon with the format "mmYYYY" and tests for bizday. Keeps substracting one day at a time until is.bizday returns TRUE so the condition !is.bizday goes for FALSE and breaks. (should)

I get "Condition has length greater than 1 in while loop" and don´t know where the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you googled that error already?

Comment: What is your input? Please provide a minimum example of `mesanio`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. The function works fine for me. Are you inputting a vector of dates?

Comment: d <- UltDiaLabor ("042014") could be a valid use and defines the type of data that mesanio contains.

Comment: `is.bizday` is probably vectorized and `!` certainly is, so you are giving a vector of length greater than 1  to `while` which is not vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to use the function with a vector of dates, but there is no way to evaluate the logical operator in the while loop with more than one value. I suggest you instead use `sapply()`.

```
date <- "122001"
dates <- c("122001", "091999")

UltDiaLabor(date) # works
UltDiaLabor(dates) # does not work
sapply(dates, UltDiaLabor) # works
```

Comment: I understand that should not work with vector and should use  sapply for that. But even using it with a date, while loop gives me the error stated in the subject .

Comment: Don´t know how to test that. str(!is.bizday(ult)) The result is: logi FALSE. How can i test if it is vector or not?

Comment: Well, finally found the problem. The function works fine, but ult was vectorized, so is.bizday was returning a vector. Thanks!